# Specifying dev-dependencies through Cargo feature flags

Tags: rust, dependencies

#### The Background

I am working on a Rust crate. It has several `[dependencies]` and several `[dev-dependencies]`. Some dev-dependencies are new crates, but some are just enabling features of crates that are already specified as dependencies.

For example, I use `serde` in my crate, but don't need to derive any serialization impls. However, for my tests I do need to derive them, so my `Cargo.toml` file looked like this:

```ini
[package]
name = "example"
version = "73015087.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
path = "/dev/null"

[dependencies] 
serde = "1.0.139"

[dev-dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.139", features = ["derive"] }
```

I didn't like needing to duplicate the version number where I (or tools) might forget to update it in sync with the other one, so I changed the dev-dependency to use an unbounded version:

```ini
[dev-dependencies]
serde = { version = ">=0", features = ["derive"] }
```

This felt kind-of gross (particularly since we need to work around `crates.io` forbidding truly unbounded versions with `*`). I don't want to be specifying a second dependency on `serde`, I just want to enable a feature. I ended up with the following alternative.

#### The Idea

Instead of specifying my dev-dependencies directly under `[dev-dependencies]`, I specified a dependency back on the crate itself, but with a feature flag named `dev-dependencies` enabled. I used the this flag to enable `serde`'s `derive` feature without needing to duplicate the version number or use an unbounded range:

```ini
[package]
name = "example"
version = "73015087.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
path = "/dev/null"

[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.139"

[dev-dependencies]
example = { path = ".", default-features = false, features = ["dev-dependencies"] }

[features]
dev-dependencies = [
  "serde/derive",
]
```

After playing with this, I realized that I could use this to list all the versions of all types of dependencies under `[dependencies]`, by adding them as optional and enabling them through the new flag. For example, here is how I've added `expect-test`, instead of putting it under `dev-dependencies`.

```ini
[package]
name = "example"
version = "73015087.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
path = "/dev/null"

[dependencies]
expect-test = { version = "1.3.0", optional = true }
serde = "1.0.139"

[dev-dependencies]
example = { path = ".", default-features = false, features = ["dev-dependencies"] }

[features]
dev-dependencies = [
  "serde/derive",
  "expect-test",
]
```

It's a little weird, but I might prefer to have all of the versions in one place and avoid the potential duplication. I'm deciding whether to stick with it.

#### The Question

Does this produce any significant differences in behaviour from expressing dev-dependencies the conventional way, or is it equivalent? Am I going to end up with more confusing resolver issues down the line?

Here are the resolutions with and without `dev` dependencies enabled, according to [cargo-tree](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html):

```
$ cargo tree -e normal
example v73015087.0.0 (/workspaces/example)
└── serde v1.0.139
```

```
$ cargo tree -e normal,dev
example v73015087.0.0 (/workspaces/example)
├── expect-test v1.3.0
│   ├── dissimilar v1.0.4
│   └── once_cell v1.13.0
└── serde v1.0.139
    └── serde_derive v1.0.139 (proc-macro)
        ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.40
        │   └── unicode-ident v1.0.2
        ├── quote v1.0.20
        │   └── proc-macro2 v1.0.40 (*)
        └── syn v1.0.98
            ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.40 (*)
            ├── quote v1.0.20 (*)
            └── unicode-ident v1.0.2
[dev-dependencies]
└── example v73015087.0.0 (/workspaces/example) (*)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. If it has no issues building, then I guess it is fine? I would have expected you to run into issues with circular dependencies in a situation where your crate gets built twice. One version without the dev-dependencies that depends on a version of your crate with `dev-dependencies` enabled. I would not trust this to build under future releases of Rust. That being said, it seems highly unlikely that cargo would choose different versions for dev dependencies if both version strings are the same even if the features differ so that may be the easier solution.

Comment: @Locke hmm good thought let me go check whether i'm getting duplicate crates compiled or not. also I realize in my examples above I left out `edition`, thinking it was irrelevant but it affects the resolver so maybe this doesn't repo exactly. i'll fix that.

Comment: I updated the example so it actually compiles (sorry) and added the resolutions according to cargo-tree. I haven't used this tool before but I think it's saying that everything's being merged appropirately.